# View behaves differently when called from WillResignActive than DidBecomeActive

Tags: ios, swift

I reset my UI with this method:

```
func resetUI () {
    self.position = 0.0
    self.percent2 = 0.0
    self.tableView.setContentOffset( CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) , animated: true)
}
```

And then have a background overlay that animates with:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let height: CGFloat = scrollView.bounds.size.height
    self.position = max(scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0.0)
    self.percent2 = min(position / height, 0.99)
    alphaView?.alpha = percent2
    extraView?.alpha = percent2
}
```

But when I call `resetUI` from **`UIApplicationWillResignActive` it works great**, when I call it from **`UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` it doesn't work great** because the blur effect doesn't show up when you scroll anymore.

Any ideas why this would happen?  I'm not sure why this would work perfect in `UIApplicationWillResignActive`but not `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive`.

*Here's how the overlay gets set up, if needed:*

```
     let overlay = UIVisualEffectView()
     overlay.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .extraLight)
     overlay.alpha = 1.0
     overlay.frame = self.view.bounds
     alphaView?.addSubview(overlay)
```

*Here's how I'm being notified of the the `UIApplication` details, if needed:*

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(resetUI),
        name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive,
        object: nil)
```

Comment: This is within a view controller I take it? Why are you listening for any application-level events instead of just doing this inside of `viewDidLoad`/`viewDidAppear`?

Comment: @ConnorNeville yeah this is within a View Controller.  I'm adding the notification observers inside of ViewDidLoad.  The problem I was having was that `viewDidLoad` wouldn't get called when the app goes into Multitasking mode and then comes back into the foreground (the only things that get called in that case are `WillResignActive` and `DidBecomeActive`), so I wasn't able to reset my UI when the application came into the foreground.  Does that make sense? And I'm not sure if I'm doing it in the best way, but its the only way I've found?

Comment: Have you tried putting it in `viewDidAppear`? That should get called upon returning to the foreground, I think.

Comment: @ConnorNeville thats the weird thing is that it actually doesn't get called in that case.  I assumed it would too!

Comment: Huh. You're right. Try using the NSNotification `UIApplicationWillEnterForeground`.

Comment: @ConnorNeville I originally was using that, but it didn't get called when you do the Multitasking thing and come back to the app (Double click home button to get to Multitasking, then tap app to bring back into foreground), so that's why I've had to dig into WillResignActive and DidBecomeActive, because is the only thing that gets called when app gets put into Multitasking and DidBecomeActive is the only thing that gets called when app comes back straight from Multitasking, from my testing.